# Gazebo documentation not in HTML format

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, documentation, rosdoc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking at the C Turtle Gazebo documentation in /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/doc. I built C Turtle on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS machine. The Gazebo HTML files are not in HTML format. For example, here is the beginning of mainpage.html:

/** \mainpage Gazebo

Gazebo is a multi-robot simulator for both indoor and outdoor
environments.  Like Stage, it is capable of simulating a population of

It appears that the documentation is in Doxygen format. I ran "rosmake simulator_gazebo", which said everything had been built correctly. Is there something else I need to do to get HTML Gazebo documentation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9372/gazebo-documentation-not-in-html-format/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general to generate the html form of documentation found on the wiki use the [rosdoc](http://ros.org/wiki/rosdoc) tool

`rosrun rosdoc rosdoc gazebo`

should generate the output you want.  Note it will generate a folder "doc" in the current working directory with it's output.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1